# What is the difference between sqlcontext.read.json and spark.read.json

Tags: apache-spark

I am testing read json in spark, I know there are two ways to read json file, `spark.read.json` and `sqlContext.read.json`

What is the difference between `spark.read.json` and `sqlContext.read.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is `spark.read` is in Spark 2 as it is a convention for the spark session.

And `sqlContext` is the way to read in spark 1, and is not available anymore in spark2